# Azure deployment has machine specific delays

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy

I'm deploying from Visual Studio to an Azure instance as part of a small team, and we've found that deployment behavior depends on which machine was last used to deploy.

If we change which machine we deploy from, the deployment updates a large list of DLLs and CSS files, even though they're unchanged from the previous deployment. If the same machine is used more than once, all deployments after the first are smooth and take very few updates.

Is there a known reason for this behavior that I've been unable to find, and is there a way to avoid updating unchanged files?

Comment: That's interesting. Do the machines have different compiler settings enabled? That might be causing the files to be different. The CSS files are an interesting case. Try manually comparing the CSS files generated by the two machines and see if you can spot any differences.

Comment: I'll check out the compiler settings - they haven't been intentionally changed, but it's possible that one has a newer version with different defaults.

The CSS files have identical text, so all I can think is that either some other file is forcing them to update or they have some relative path that looks different to Azure.

Comment: How are you deploying? Deployment from Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, the deployment is directly from Visual Studio, and things like ensuring a clean build haven't changed the results.  It looks from your answer below like that may be our issue.

Answer (score 0):

While deploying manualy from Visual Studio is nice for getting a prototype working, it isn't consired as best practice to build and deploy from a local development machine, since the result strongly depends on how the local machine is configured, which DLLs are in GAC, etc... This may also be one of your problem, but this is realy hard to debug.

So I strongly recommend either using deploy through source control or using a build server like TeamCity, Jenkins or similar to deploy.

Deployment with source control are realy easy to setup. You can follow the [this guide](http://blog.yannisguedel.ch/2015/07/03/continuous-deployment-on-azure-app-services/) in order to get started.

Comment: Thanks, this may be related.  I've just read through your post about continuous deployment, though, and I have a significant question.  The code we're using is already shared under source control (including lists of package versions, but excluding the packages themselves).  Given that the same code is in use, what changes between deploying source-controlled code from Visual Studio, and deploying directly from that source?

Comment: If you are using NuGet as package manager and if your repository only contains one website-project no change should be required. Azure automatically detect the solution to build and the website-project to build.

The difference is that when build and deploy is done by Azure, the build environment is consistent. On your local machines the result of the build depends on what is installed on the machine. On of your colleage may have Visual Studio 2015 also installed for example. There are lot of system-wide things which have an impact on how DLLs are linked.